# If/else condition with firebase value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement, logical-operators

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> 
{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> studentNameList;
    ArrayList<String> studentMatrikList;
    ArrayList<String> studentPhoneList;
    ArrayList<String> studentAddressList;
    ArrayList<String> studentStatusList;
    ArrayList<String> studentMailList;
    ArrayList<String> studentConList;
    ArrayList<String> studentIdList;

    class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       TextView studentName, studentMatrik, studentPhone, studentAddress, studentStatus, studentMail, studentCon, studentId, Check;
       CheckBox checkBox;
       Button buttonMap;
       DatabaseReference databaseReference;

       public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          studentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
          studentMatrik = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMatrik);
          studentPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentPhone);
          studentAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentAddress);
          studentStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentStatus);
          studentMail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentMail);
          studentCon = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentCon);
          studentId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentId);
          checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

          String name = studentName.getText().toString();

          if(name.equals("a")){
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
          }else{
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
          }

          buttonMap = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);
          buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Latitude",studentMail.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude",studentCon.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Address",studentAddress.getText().toString());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    String id = studentId.getText().toString();
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student");
                    String name = "Check";
                    databaseReference.child(id).child("stat").setValue(name);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    String id = studentId.getText().toString();
                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("student");
                    String name = "Not Check";
                    databaseReference.child(id).child("stat").setValue(name);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I retrieve all the data from firebase to recyclerview textview itemview. When I try the if/else condition in adapter, it compares against the textview android:text in the XML, not the firebase data value. Why does is this happen?

```
studentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);

        String name = studentName.getText().toString();
        if(name.equals("a")){
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
```

It compares with the textview android:text in xml not the firebase value...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/studentName"
    android:layout_width="205dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name goes here"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: just a tip: always keep your code short and clear where possible. For instance, change this: if(name.equals("a")){
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            checkBox.setChecked(false);
        } to this:
checkBox.setChecked("a".equals(name));

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the value first on you textview which you have received from firebase. other wise it will keep getting the value as set default in your xml.